# Limit of a sequence in dependency to x

Tags: analysis

Calculate the limit of $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(cos(n!x))^{2k} $$ in dependency to x $$\\$$
Since $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(cos(n!x))^{2k} = 0\\ $$ I don't know how can I continue.

Comment: What is the expression? Is it $\cos( n! x)$ ? Or $\cos(n!) \cdot x$?

Comment: Typo is corrected.

Comment: Note that for $x=\pi$ and $n\geq 2$ you have $\cos(n!\pi)=1$.

Comment: Compute first $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\cos(n!x))^{2k}$. You can think of $n$ to be large, while doing so. If $x=\pi\frac{p}{q}$, with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\neq0$, then the $n!$ will cancel the $q$ and we get cosine of an integer multiple of $\pi$. That is $\pm1$. That raised to $2k$ is $1$. Now, if $x$ is anything else, then the cosine is in $(-1,1)$. When we raise it to $2k$ and tend $k\to\infty$, the power tends to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} (\cos(n!x))^{2k}=0$$
if $$|\cos(n!x)|<1.$$

This will only not be the case when $\cos(n!x)=1$ or $\cos(n!x)=-1$. We solve this to get $$n!x=2\pi j \;\;\text{and}\;\; n!x=\pi+2\pi j$$
for $j\in \mathbb Z$. I.e.
$$x=\frac{2\pi}{n!}j \;\;\text{and}\;\; x=\frac{\pi+2\pi}{n!} j.$$
And since $n \to \infty$ we must have that $x=0$ is the only exception.

Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty} (\cos(n!x))^{2k} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it now